# webClient.DownloadFile error : The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, download, webclient, mp4

I am trying to simply download an `mp4` file via embedded server application using this code :
http://videovlt is server application which is located under virtual pc.
and the code below runs on an embedded server application which is running under my pc.

spath = "http://videovlt/videos/7bf9d10b-4006-4b44-9626-e3751df2f4ce.mp4"

fpath = "E:\videos\7bf9d10b-4006-4b44-9626-e3751df2f4ce.mp4"

```
webClient.DownloadFile(spath, fpath);
```

Its not working though and it gives this error :

> "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."

I am unable to understand the reason as to why this error is coming up.
I tried adding the below code as well but still the issue is there :

```
webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 9.0; en-US)");
```

Need some suggestions to proceed here.

I have renamed the video name to "1" and same error..

Comment: Error 500 indicates that something went wrong at the server-side. What that is, we cannot possibly tell you. If possible check the logs on the server, to see what is going wrong. If you do not have access to that server's logs, I need to contact the person responsible for the service.

Comment: Without seeing the URL its going to be very difficult to help you. Does it have spaces? Special characters?

Comment: You should post more of youre code for anyone to help you out here.

Comment: I have updated the question with string values, by the way once I run the "http://videovlt/videos/7bf9d10b-4006-4b44-9626-e3751df2f4ce.mp4" from browser the video plays..

Comment: When I use  webClient.DownloadFileAsync it creates file with 0 kb..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was source mp4 url was getting broken before consumed by embedded server.